# Rails inclusion validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, validation

I'm struggling to get a inclusion validation to work on a model so maybe some one could tell me what I'm missing here.

This is the model I have:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  ORDER_TYPES = %w{ Verkooporder Retourorder }

  ORDER_TYPES.each_with_index do |meth, index|
    define_method("#{meth}?") { type == index }
  end
  validates_inclusion_of :order_type, :in =>  %w{ Verkooporder Retourorder }
  ...
```

I also created a form that creates a dropdownbox using the constant array like this:
(I'm

```
 = f.input :order_type, as: :select, collection: Order::ORDER_TYPES, label: 'Order type', include_blank: false
```

And I save it to my model like this:

```
@order.order_type =   params[:order][:order_type]
```

So when I save my order model it always fails on validating the order_type.
Is there anybody who can point me out what I'm doing wrong?

PS: The order_type is an integer value field in my model.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are defining methods `Verkooporder?` and `Retourorder?`, but they're not being called from your validation because the `:in` is interpreting `%w{ Verkooporder Retourorder}` as an array of strings, i.e. `[ "Verkooporder", "Retourorder"]`.

What you actually want to validate is that `order_type` is a number between 0 and the size of the `ORDER_TYPES` array, i.e. a string with a value between 0 and 1:

```
validates_inclusion_of :order_type, :in => %w{ 0 1 }
```

In this case you don't really need to define the boolean `Verkooporder?` and `Retourorder?` methods, unless you need them elsewhere.

UPDATE:

I realize now that your form will return `order_type` as a string in `Order::ORDER_TYPES`, which won't work with the validation above since the validation above is validating on integer-valued strings.

The way I've done this in the past is not to use an integer for `order_type` but a string. In that case, you can just validate with `validates_inclusion_of :order_type, :in => ORDER_TYPES`, and the select drop-down doesn't have to change. Is there any particular reason you're using an integer value field for `order_type`? Alternatively you could have the select return integer values for each order type.

Comment: Also try using the new Rails 3 validation style if you are working with Rails 3.  <br/>
<code>validates :order_type, :inclusion => { :in => %w(0 1) } </code>